# Abbreviation with parentheses

Tags: periods

Which is correct?

I work for Jan-Carol Graphics (JCG).
or
I work for Jan-Carol Graphics (JCG.)

Comment: Hmm, I can see nothing, at all, about this unusual situation, on the linked question.

Comment: @Joe Blow - From the linked answer: If the parenthetical material is part of another sentence, place the period outside the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Your question seems to be based on the assumption that JCG should properly be followed by a period to indicate that it is an abbreviation.  That is incorrect.  It would generally be rendered as "JCG" without periods, or as "J.C.G." with a period after each letter.